# Custom Faker Provider: Reuse city

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-factory

I built a custom Faker Provider to generate team names.

This is how that looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Faker;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Faker\Provider\Base;

class TeamProvider extends Base
{
    ...

    public function teamName()
    {
       
        $name[] = static::randomElement(static::$prefixes);
        ...
        $name[] = $this->generator->city;
        //some more stuff to create a nice team name

        return implode(" ", $name);
    }
}
```

This works fine in my Factory:

```
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->teamName,
            'city' => $this->faker->city
        ];
    }
```

But: The `TeamProvider` generates a city and this is not the same city the Factory's faker is generating.

So the `teamName` is (just an example) `AC Glasgow 1990` and the city of `AC Glasgow` is `London` ;-)  This does not make a lot of sense ;-)

So my question is: How can I reuse the `city` in this case to get valid results?

Answer (score 0):

As I read through the docs again I mentioned my problem. Faker is not used to create data that are somehow "logically" related just like real person's data. It just fills model's fields with valid data. So it's useful for tinkering and testing, but not for bootstrapping some valid and consistent data.